# DB::select returning different results than mysql command line

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent, laravel-5

I'm trying to rename some columns in a MySQL database, but unfortunately the table contains an `enum` so `doctrine\dbal` throws an error. I decided to write my own rename function using raw sql, but some of the checks I'm putting into place are failing and I don't know why.

When I'm in the MySQL CLI, I run this query:

```
select table_name from information_schema where table_name = "my_table" and table_schema = "my_schema";
```

This returns one row with the table name, as expected. So I figured in my migration, I could do this:

```
$exists = Schema::hasTable('my_table');
```

but that returned `false`. Weird, I thought, so let's take the whole `Schema` thing out of the equation and just try straight sql against `information_schema`.

```
$result = DB::select('select table_name from information_schema where table_name = ? and table_schema = ?', ['my_table', 'my_schema']);
```

However, when I run that statement, the value of `$result` is `[]`. I thought maybe the compiled sql might be wrong, so I `dump`ed out the return from `DB::getQueryLog()`, but it all looks correct:

```
array:1 [
    0 => array:3 [
        "query" => "select table_name from information_schema.tables where table_name = ? and table_schema = ?;"
        "bindings" => array:2 [
            0 => "my_table"
            1 => "my_schema"
        ]
        "time" => 0.01
    ]
]
```

I should point out that when I run `php artisan tinker` and run that same `DB::select()` statement, I get the results I'm looking for, so it seems that it's not working just within the migration file.

I'm at a loss. Why would `DB::select()` return different results than running the exact same query on the MySQL CLI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a workaround for the moment. I created a second identical connection profile in my `config/database.php` file that has the same connection information as `my_schema` except I changed `database` to `information_schema`. In my migration, I'm using the following:

```
DB::connection('my_informationschema')->select('select table_name from information_schema where table_name = ? and table_schema = ?', ['my_table', 'my_schema']);
```

and that's returning what I need. So it seems like the application will let you play fast and loose with the schema when using raw queries, except when you're in a migration?

Answer (score 0):

Plz use DB:raw('select table_name from information_schema where table_name = "my_table" and table_schema = "my_schema"');

Comment: No go: `dd(DB::select(DB::raw('select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = "my_schema"')));` returns `[]`.